# Karate Unable to pass JSON into feature file

Tags: javascript, dsl, karate

**code attempted**

```
  * def createTariffResponse = call read ('create-customer-mileage-tariff.feature') { id: '#(serviceId)' }
```

**exception**

```
-unknown-:9 - javascript evaluation failed: ('create-customer-mileage-tariff.feature') { id: '#(serviceId)' }, <eval>:1:43 Expected ; but found {
('create-customer-mileage-tariff.feature') { id: '#(serviceId)' }
                                           ^ in <eval> at line number 1 at column number 43
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space between the `read` and `(`.

If that doesn't work, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Losing my mind over a single space, thanks @peter-thomas this fixed the issue! no need to raise any issues!

Comment: \*phew\* that was easy :)